# How to suppress echo of buggy read function

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, read

I'm trying to capture a key press in a shell script (e.g. using `read`) and not to echo it. The three methods I found were `stty -echo`, the `-s` switch and stream redirection.

However, on macOS, which seems to use a FreeBSD implementation, none of these work consistently.

The following script shows the issue:

```
while true; do
    stty -echo
    read -s -n 1 CHAR &>/dev/null
    stty echo
done
```

When pressing the up and down arrows at the same time, sometimes the command echoes `A^[[B` or `B^[[A`. This occurs particularly often when the machine is slow (due to low battery), indicating some race condition.

Am I missing something? Otherwise, how can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, there is a short window of time between the "stty echo" at the end of the loop and the "stty -echo" at the next iteration. Keyboard input received during this window will be echoed, even though no read command is waiting for it. If you don't want echoes, don't call "stty echo"

Comment: That was surprisingly simple :) I was under the assumption that this would disable stdout entirely (i.e. disable `echo`), but only now I see that this isn't the case.

Comment: You're welcome :-) But remember to run stty echo at the end of your script so the user is not surprised that keyboard input is hidden after they ran your script.

Comment: Better yet, add the `stty echo` to a trap, further lessening user surprise when they press `^C`.